# why my merge sort for lists doesnt work -c

Tags: c, mergesort

I'm sending to the merge sort function head of the list and somehow it disappear organs of the least, I sent 10 appartment that are in the list and it should merge by max price, I notice that when it returns with the back it getting recursively from the function the apartment number 9(the head of the apartment from 6 to 10) but somehow it get the apartment number 6 as the first.
I use this function to my project in school and I need to submit it until next week, so I will really appreciate help in the next few days, Thank you from advance.

```
void MergeSort(ApNode *head)
{

    ApNode *front, *back;
    if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
    {
        return;
    }
    else {//lst not empty
        front = (ApNode*)malloc(sizeof(ApNode));
        back = (ApNode*)malloc(sizeof(ApNode));
        /* Split head into 'front' and 'back' sublists */
        FrontBackSplit(head, &front, &back);

        /* Recursively sort the sublists */
        MergeSort(front);
        MergeSort(back);
        head = merge(front, back);
    }
    return;
}

void FrontBackSplit(ApNode* source, ApNode** frontRef, ApNode** backRef)
{

    ApNode* fast;
    ApNode* slow;
    if (source == NULL || source->next == NULL)
    {
        /* length < 2 cases */
        *frontRef = source;
        *backRef = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        slow = source;
        fast = source->next;

        /* Advance 'fast' two nodes, and advance 'slow' one node */
        while (fast != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next;
            if (fast != NULL)
            {
                slow = slow->next;
                fast = fast->next;
            }
        }

        /* 'slow' is before the midpoint in the list, so split it in two
        at that point. */
        *frontRef = source;
        *backRef = slow->next;
        slow->next = NULL;
    }
}

ApNode* merge(ApNode* head1, ApNode * head2)
{

    ApNode * curr1 = head1;
    ApNode * curr2 = head2;
    ListAp lst3;
    makeEmptyApList(&lst3);
    while ((curr1 != NULL) && (curr2 != NULL))
    {
        if ((curr1->price)<(curr2->price))
        {
            addAp(&lst3, curr1);
            curr1 = curr1->next;
        }
        else
        {
            addAp(&lst3, curr2);
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        }
    }
    while (curr1 != NULL)
    {
        addAp(&lst3, curr1);
        curr1 = curr1->next;
    }
    while (curr2 != NULL)
    {
        addAp(&lst3, curr2);
        curr2 = curr2->next;
    }
    return lst3.head;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you haven't prototyped  `FrontBackSplit(head, &front, &back);`before call. Than the compiler could not recognize the function. Try to put `FrontBackSplit(ApNode* source, ApNode** frontRef, ApNode** backRef)` function before `void MergeSort(ApNode *head)`.